# Twitter bootstrap footer too low

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter bootstrap with a template I purchased. I had to do a bit of work to get the footer to appear and look acceptable, but now it is always too low.

What I mean is, white space will always be added so that the footer is below the bottom of the screen - you always have to scroll down to see it.

[Here's a link to the site](http://www.mylifelessons.net). You only need to look at the homepage to see the problem.

Comment: When the issue is fixed, I will remove the link and add any detail missing from the correct answer so the results are reproducable.

Comment: first of all, the weird little whitespace below the footer is caused because your `.footer` is set to fixed `height:20px`. Remove that and it will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the extra white spacing that is causing your page to grow more then it should, just remove:

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

If what you are trying to achiev with the footer, is to allways stick it on the bottom of the page you should follow a technique called sticky footer something like [this](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/)

Comment: It currently sticks to the bottom of the page (not the screen) but there is always white space inserted so I have to scroll down to see it. when there is no content, then I want to appear on the screen without scrolling

Comment: Incredible mfreitas. I hope something unexpectedly brilliant happens to you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have the #wrap element set to 'min-height: 100%;'.  If you are ok with the footer just being at the bottom of the content rather than the bottom of the page then removing that should be an easy fix.